# How to autocmd BufWritePost stdout to tidy upon :w?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

tldr;

How do pass stdout of BufWritePost to an external command?

On command line I can run:

```
cat index.html | tidy -indent -modify
```

I'm trying to call tidy automatically when I `:w`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
:function! Tidy()
:  call tidy -indent -modify --doctype omit --show-body-only yes 
:endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *.html call Tidy()
```

I'm missing some vimscript skills

Comment: Probably you just need to use a filter (`:help filter` should get you there; something like `:%!tidy …`). Otherwise there are system/sytemlist. You might want BufWritePre if you change the contents.

Comment: Thanks, what is the meaning of % in this context? Yes BufWritePre makes more sense

Comment: Try `:help [range]`; it means filter (!) the whole buffer (%)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the intent is to replace the contents with the `tidy`’d contents before writing, I would use `BufWritePre` and a filter like

```
:%!tidy …
```

This gives the buffer as standard in and replaces it with standard out.

Comment: I wouldn't use it in `BufWritePre` though. One might end up saving a "corrupted" html.